# How Do I Map a Drive Network Share Using the Linux Terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, network-shares

Still getting used to Linux, and the GUI is great.  I have Ubuntu 10 and I can go to Network and see the Windows network.  Then double clicking this gets me to the drives that are shared.  Then when I go back to the terminal and use:

`cd ~/.gvfs`

I can see the mapped drives.  But it would be nice if I could this without all the mouse clicking.  So how do I map network drives in the terminal, something akin to `net use` for Windows.

**EDIT**:  Not sure what happened, but this is what I did to get it to work.  I created the directory for the share in `/media` and then ran:

`sudo mount -t cifs -o username=nicorellius //server/share/ /media/share`

and it said command couldn't be found.  So i thought I would go ahead and use `smbfs` so I ran:

`sudo apt-get install smbfs`

I tried the command suggested with `smbfs` instead of `cifs` and that didn't work either.  So I tried again and then the next time I ran:

`sudo mount -t cifs -o username=nicorellius //server/share/ /media/share`

it worked and I could navigate to the directory with `cd`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Create a directory on your machine to use as a mount point for the share:

```
sudo mkdir /media/yoursharename
```

Then use the mount command to map a Windows share to the mount point you just created:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=nicorellius //server/sharename /media/yoursharename
```

You should now be to access the share from your **/media/yoursharename** mount point.

Comment: Isn't Samba already installed?  Is it not the program that is accessing the share when I go to Places > Network and find the Windows network?

Comment: Samba is already installed, but smbfs for mounting remote file systems isn't by default on Ubuntu, I've used this method for for a long time but I've just checked and cifs seems to have superseded smbfs and I imagine the gui is mounting the drive using cifs as well.  I've modified the mount command to the cifs version in my original answer.  You should be to run this without installing any extra packages.

Comment: See edit in my question for what I did to make it work...

Comment: Oddly enough, I tried this on the other share I needed access to and it didn't work.  Something about the IP address or sever name...  So I tried with the local IP 192.168.x.x and this worked as well.  Great help, John - Thanks!

Comment: what is `cifs`?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira It's kind of the same as `smb`. And you have to have `cifs-utils` installed for the `mount` command to work.

Answer (score 7):

`gvfs-mount` can be used to mount filesystems under `~/.gvfs` in the same manner as Gnome applications.

Comment: syntax would be:

    `gvfs-mount mount smb://username@server.tld/share`

You may have to create a bookmark first.